# Update single list item RXJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I basically want to convert this for loop to an Observable

```
private static List<Book> books

public static void replaceBook(Book book) {
    for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
        if (books.get(i).getId().equals(book.getId())) {
            books.set(i, book);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far but its not working. I thought the map operator would update the filtered item but I seem to be missing something.

```
Observable.from(books).filter(new Func1<Book, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Book b) {
            return b.getId().equals(book.getId());
        }
    }).map(new Func1<Book, Book>() {
        @Override
        public Book call(Book b) {
            return book;
        }
    }).subscribe();
```

Update

Based on Boris and Tassos's answers I got the following answer which seems to work

```
  Observable.from(books)
            .map(b -> b.getId().equals(book.getId()) ? book : b)
            .toList()
            .subscribe(s -> books = s);
```

Comment: do you want 'filter' some elements from `List<Books>`? Or replace some Book in list and return list?

Comment: I want to replace the list item and return the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
Observable
  .from(books)
  .map(new Func1<Book, Book>() {
        @Override
        public Book call(Book b) {
            if (book.getId().equals(b.getId()))
                return book;
            return b;
        }
  })
  .toList()
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Observable
  .from(books)
  .map(b ->  b.getId().equals(book.getId()) ? book : b)
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to update the List<Book> books once it finishes. Do I need to add something in subscribe to update the instance of the list?

Comment: Don't use Rx for this, as it's not the right tool for the job - Rx lends itself to a more functional style with mostly-immutable data structures. Otherwise just do a .toList().

Comment: Alternatively use `books.replaceAll(b ->  b.getId().equals(book.getId()) ? book : b);`